# Volley not getting to URL in app, Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley

Just finishing my app and using Volley to pull data from my database and put it into the app. I have 2 phones for testing, works fine on 1, but not on the other. It's not even hitting the server (nothing in the logs). Tried it on 4G and WiFi (same WiFi network as the other, working, phone is on).

I cannot work this out. The phone can connect to the internet fine in app, it uses Google Play Games and a test advert, I've also put the link straight into Chrome on the phone and it's fine like that. Also tried other urls, like Google and it fails with that too. There's no errors on the logcat.

The only difference between the 2 is that one is on Android 7 (works fine), the other is on Android 10 Pixel 3A (the app has "no special permissions" and is greyed out in settings)

This is the code:

```
var dbURLcheckData = "http://myURLgoesHere.com/App/sql/dbRestoreData.php"
//dbURLcheckData = "http://google.com"
val urlTextField = findViewById<TextView>(com.company.appName.R.id.urlForTestingRestore)
urlTextField.text = dbURLcheckData

val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val stringRequest = StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, dbURLcheckData,
    Response.Listener<String> { response ->
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"response: $response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    },
    Response.ErrorListener {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"error getting backup data\n$dbURLcheckData", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // this is the things that always shows up on one phone, the other phone is successful
    })

queue.add(stringRequest)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make changes in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<application
    ....
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

The issue is with http on latest android versions. Adding above line into application tag will fix it.

Comment: Works, fantastic, thank you!
will mark as answer when it allows me

Comment: You are Welcome!

Comment: The above workaround will allow the app to use HTTP instead of HTTPS protocol... for now.  But maybe not forever.  Google is making a commitment towards more secure computing standards, so, the real solution is to use HTTPS, not HTTP.